# Umbraco 7.2.0 - grid.editors.config.js is cached and will not update

Tags: caching, umbraco, umbraco7, client-dependency

I have created a new grid editor, and have deployed it to my production server. When on my development machine, a change to the `grid.editors.config.js` is reflected immediately.

However, on my production server, a change to `grid.editors.config.js` has no effect.

After some research, I have found that the issue is probably the client dependency cache. I have tried the following:

- Removing the files from `App_Data/TEMP/ClientDependency`
- Incrementing the version number in `Config/ClientDependency.config`
- Recycling the application pool
- Clearing the browser cache
- Restarting the server

What am I missing? When I add a query string, ie. `https://mywebsite/config/grid.editors.config.js?v=1` then the changes are shown, which means the file has definitely updated on the server.

What do I need to do to update the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was caused by a third party that provides DDoS protection to the site - content was cached via the third party and so changes to files were not being reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any expiration headers for caching js on your website?

You could try to delete the following files:

```
App_Data/TEMP/DistCache

App_Data/TEMP/PluginCache
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that it's a simple case of the browser caching your assets locally. You can usually force a refresh by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and clicking refresh in your web browser and the changes are then visible.